# Drupal module Printer, email and PDF versions send mail without HTML

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to use the function "Send this page by email" with the module "Printer, email and PDF versions", but the email is sent in an HTML format (with header, meta, etc). The problem is that my website already have a mail template, so when the mail is sent from the module it has the template and the html inside.

Do you know how can I proceed to send only the content of the html (not the headers / footers).

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a new key in mailsystem for your "print_email" module and assign it a different template.

Comment: The thing is that I want to keep the same template (there is an header image, and a footer that are the same for all the mail), I think i'm close to the solution but in my mail I still have the debug informations (ex: <!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- CALL: theme('print') --> <!-- FILE ) but they will disapear when I will disabled them. But the other problem is that the html is not considered like html. So my paragraph and bold doesn't work